# c# Asp.Net проблема связки событий и Hub(хабов) из SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, события, делегаты, signalr

Делаю мессенджер. Хочу создать **event**, который будет реагировать на изменение списка пользователей(обычный массив) и отправлять всем подключенным пользователям этот список.

Но проблема в том, что **Hub** имеет специфичный жизненный цикл, и у меня не получается где-то грамотно и единожды инициализировать метод, который будет вызываться при событии.
Как понимаю, каждый **экземпляр Hub'a**  содержит свой контекст для каждого пользователя, и "умирает" после выполнения запроса.
**ChatManager** у меня **статичен** и один для всех хабов. Само событие лежит в **ChatManager**

**ChatHub**

```
internal class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly static ChatManager ChatManager = new ChatManager(); // тут всякая логика

        public async Task SendMembersInfo() // метод, который хочу вызывать при событии
        {
            MembersInfo membersInfo = ChatManager.CreateMembersInfo();
            string jsonMembersInfo = JsonHelper.Serialize(membersInfo);
            await this.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMembersInfo", jsonMembersInfo);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            ChatManager.ConnectUser(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            ChatManager.DisconnectUser(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

**ChatManager**

```
namespace ServerSide.Models
{
    internal class ChatManager
    {
        public List<User> Users { get; } = new List<User>();

        public delegate Task Update(); 
        public event Update OnUsersUpdate; // EVENT

        public MembersInfo CreateMembersInfo()
        {
            return new MembersInfo(Users);
        }

        public bool ConnectUser(string connectionId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionId)) return false;
            if (Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.ConnectionId == connectionId) != null) return false;

            Users.Add(new User(connectionId));
            OnUsersUpdate(); // вызываю событие
            return true;
        }
        public void DisconnectUser(string connectionId)
        {
            User? user = Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.ConnectionId == connectionId);
            if (user == null) return;

            Users.Remove(user);
            OnUsersUpdate(); // вызываю событие
        }

    }
}
```

**Где подключить событие в ChatHub**?

Все прекрасно работает, если в конструкторе Хаба инициализировать работу с событием, но ведь это получается, что он привязывается много раз. Можно ли как-то грамотно его привязать?

```
public ChatHub()
{
    ChatManager.OnUsersUpdate += this.SendMembersInfo;
}
```

Буду благодарен за предложения.

Comment: Обратите внимание, `List<T>` не является потокобезопасной коллекцией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите статику

```
private readonly static ChatManager ChatManager = new ChatManager()`
```

Вставьте зависимость на ChatManager через конструктор

```
private readonly ChatManager _сhatManager;

public ChatHub(ChatManager сhatManager)
{
    _chatManager = сhatManager;
}
```

Зарегистрируйте ChatManager в IoC:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ChatManager>();
```

И прокидывайте Hub во все вызовы `ChatManager`, где нужно отправить сообщение всем (ну или отправляйте прямо из Hub)

Comment: А почему нужно прокидывать **hub в ChatManager**? ChatManager - просто отделение некоторой логики, которая может быть прописана в самом хабе. То есть менеджер - зависимость для хаба, а не наоборот. Было бы логичнее в хаб прокидывать статичный объект ChatManager, что бы хаб уже вызывал там все, что надо. Вы в последнем опечатались, наверное, ибо выше писали о том, что я имею в виду. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @jorlyf ну куда логику запихивать - это уже вообще дело :) я имел ввиду, что ChatManager не должен ссылаться на конкретный Hub через поля, и если и вызывать что-то в хабе- то в переданном через параметры экземпляре.

Comment: @jorlyf я бы оставил всю логику отправки в хабе и ничего никуда не прокидывал. В любом случае - связка делается как в ответе, что дальше - на ваше усмотрение

Comment: только что применил Вашу рекомендацию о регистрации синглтона, но я не пойму, каким образом в ChatHub прилетает объект ChatManager, не могу найти информацию в документации. Он автоматически подбирает аргумент? Мне думать об этом совсем не нужно? А то магия какая-то!

Comment: @jorlyf это стандартная реализация паттернов IoC / DI в asp.net core (бувы I D в SOLID): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0. Через него стоит резолвить вообще все, от своих зависимостей между классами до системных (ILogger<ChatHub>, ILogger<ChatManager> для записи в логи, HttpClient, контексты EF, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/, вообще все подряд - почти для всего есть родные регистрации из коробки, которые добавляются опциями AddZZZ() в startup). Магия, без которой тяжело жить :)